# invalid value error in get_report function

Tags: pandas, google-api, google-analytics-api

```
def get_report(analytics):
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
              'reportRequests': 
              [
                  {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression':i} for i in METRICS],
                    'dimensions': [{'name':j} for j in DIMENSIONS]
                  }
              ]
           }
  ).execute()
```

> File "/home/mail_name/gaToPandas/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
>   googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "Invalid value 'project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' for viewId parameter.">

How can I resolve this issue?
There is an error in step 3 of this site https://www.digishuffle.com/blogs/google-analytics-reporting-python/

Comment: Please include all of your code i am not seeing the authorization part which is likely where this error is coming from.  Your error is probably in step 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Invalid value 'project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' for viewId parameter."

[image]

The view Id should be the view id from Google Analytics which you wish to request data for not the service account name.

[image]

Comment: Again this is the **View id** from GOOGLE ANALYTICS.  Go to google analytics website admin section find the view you wish to see data for copy its view id and use that.